# C# Hello world with get failing

Tags: c#

I am trying to learn a C# and I am trying to use get and set with string. However, with various errors it either refuses to compile or crash with stack overflow

```
using System;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace CshEssentials
{
    class Program
    {
        public string a
        {
            get
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Hello {a}"); return "0";
            }
            set
            {
                a = value;
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            a = Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Post the errors please

Comment: you cannot write the return statement in the getter.

Comment: Nothing to post really. Just stack overflow in console

Comment: @nabuchodonossor But without return, it says that it needs to return something

Comment: @nabuchodonossor Getters have return statements.

Comment: @Mike2233 ignore the comment about getters not allowing `return`

Comment: @nabuchodonossor You can, as long as you eventually return something from that method.

Comment: @AndréReichelt: of course you´r right ... doing this all day long and messed it up somehow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

First is that your Main function is static. That means it is a method of the `Program` type, not of an instance of a `Program`. You should either make the property static, or make sure you instantiate `Program` in `Main`.

Secondly, in your setter you are setting the property again, which leads to an infinite loop.

You can fix both problems as follows:

```
class Program
{
    // Create a backing field for the property
    private string a;

    // Conventionally properties start with a capital letter
    // (e.g. name is a private field, Name is a public property).
    public string A
    {
        get
        {
            // Unchanged, but now returns value based on the backing field
            Console.WriteLine($"Hello {a}"); return "0";
        }
        set
        {
            // Unchanged: now sets the backing field instead of calling the setter again
            a = value;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program = new Program(); // Create an instance
        program.A = Console.ReadLine();  // Set non-static property
    }
```

That being said, it is sort of *not done* to have your property getters execute with side effects, such as printing to the console. Normally you would let the property return the value and then let the caller decide what to do with it:

```
class Program
{
    // Create a backing field for the property
    private string a;

    // Conventionally properties start with a capital letter
    // (e.g. name is a private field, Name is a public property).
    public string A
    {
        get
        {
            // Returns value based on the backing field,
            // caller can decide what to do with it
            return $"Hello {a}";
        }
        set
        {
            // Unchanged: now sets the backing field instead of calling the setter again
            a = value;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program = new Program(); // Create an instance
        program.A = Console.ReadLine();  // Set non-static property
        Console.WriteLine("program.A = {program.A}"); // Get and print
    }
```

Comment: By the way, note that returning something different from the `get`ter can lead to weird effects. For example, the state of `program` depends on how often you call `program.A = program.A` consecutively.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with the setter you are creating an endless loop. Imagine, that `a = Console.ReadLine();` sends the user input into `a`. This will call the setter method, which receives the user input as `value`. You are writing this back into `a`, which will call the setter agein. And so on, and so on. It will never stop until you hit the error Stack Overflow. In reality, your computer can't call the method endlessly, because at some point, there is no memory left, so it will crash.

I would recommend you to look into the manual about getters and setters. Your example is not really realistic.

To give a simple example, how you could use getters and setters, try out this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace CshEssentials
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string aPrivate = "";

        public static string a
        {
            get
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Getter for a was called. Returning {aPrivate}.");
                return aPrivate;
            }
            set
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"a was set to {value}.");
                aPrivate = value;
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            a = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I know that it is not realistic :) Just trying to learn, how to use them

Comment: @Mike2233 I've added an example for you.

Comment: Oh, thanks :) But why it is giving me errors here - https://prnt.sc/tt66d7
If I change a to string a then it works(in main)

Comment: @Mike2233 Have you changed the variables to be `static`? I forgot that.

Comment: I haven't changed anything :) Just copied yours

Comment: @Mike2233 Yeah, I made an edit shortly after posting. Maybe you missed it.